# Can a helicopter “ditch”?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

If the verb *ditch* means "to make a forced landing of (an airplane) on water”, as Merriam-Webster [reads](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ditch), what verb can be used to mean “to make a forced landing of **(a *helicopter*)** on water”?

Or, if *ditch*, contrary to what Merriam-Webster reads and according to Andrew Leach’s definition below, is simply to make a forced landing (*ditch in a field*), what verb, possibly a single word, can be used to mean “to make a forced landing of   (an airplane) **on water**”?

Comment: *Ditch* is the word you want. [Three people are missing after a helicopter ditched in the North Sea](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-23822012). In fact *ditch* is simply to make a forced landing. It could have ditched in a field.

Comment: English doesn't have a single word which differentiates between forced landings on land and water. *Ditch* has to suffice, along with the location ("ditched in the North Sea").

Comment: @Andrew Leach, so M-W is wrong?!

Comment: Not **wrong,** just incomplete. *Ditch* **does** mean that, but it also means a forced landing by **any** aircraft, **anywhere**.

Comment: @Andrew Leach, so 'oxforddictionaries.com', too, is wrong: "bring (an aircraft) down **on water** in an emergency" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Whether or not a dictionary (or two) has documented it, *ditch* **is** used for forced landings on land.

Comment: @Andrew Leach, tell me, now, how many dictionaries one, especially a not native speaker, has to consult before judging how well a word would work in a given context?

Comment: Although some apparently argue that "ditched" can apply to both land and water, I think most readers see "ditched" as implying a water landing.  "Crash landing" or "forced landing" is more often used for forced landings on land.

Comment: Note that there is another use of "ditched" with regard to, eg, getting rid of a stolen car.  While this use may seem similar, it's quite different, as it refers to running the vehicle into a ditch, something that one would not intend with an aircraft.

Comment: If you look at "ditched the aircraft" in Google books, virtually all of the roughly twenty "hits" are referring to a water landing.  (A few are ambiguous, and a couple are probably OCR errors.)  There are also a handful of hits for "ditched the helicopter".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same word would be used for any aircraft, not just an airplane but also a helicopter.

The verb *ditch* can mean three different things:

1. “dig a ditch into”,
2. “throw into a ditch” (literal)/“abandon” (figurative), and
3. “fly into the sea” (literal).

There is probably no realistic context in which you would use sense 1 with a helicopter. You would use sense 2 when you abandon your helicopter (or throw it into a ditch). You would use sense 3 when you fly your helicopter into the sea.

Here is a little more information about these three senses of the verb.

### 1. dig a ditch into

This is the oldest sense of the verb. According to *Online Etymology Dictionary*, it was being used in the 1300s.[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ditch)

### 2. throw into a ditch

Also according to *Online Etymology Dictionary*, the verb *ditch* is first found in print in 1816 meaning “throw into a ditch”, and later in 1899 begins to be used figuratively meaning “abandon/discard”. This is an Americanism.

### 3. fly into the sea

Meanwhile, on the other bank of the Atlantic (more about that in a moment): the “fly into the sea” meaning originated as World War II British Royal Air Force slang. It turns out that, by the 1910s, *The Ditch* was already a slang term for various bodies of water: notably the Atlantic (sometimes The *Big* Ditch), the English Channel, and the North Sea. And it was, of course, into exactly these bodies of water that RAF pilots sometimes were forced to fly.

Making a verb from a noun is common in English. RAF pilots *ditched* their crafts (flew into the Ditch) like we *floor* the gas pedal (press the pedal to the floor), *plate* a meal (serve a meal on a plate), *pack* clothing (put clothing in a pack or suitcase), *shoe* a horse (put shoes on a horse) – or even *verb* a noun.

*Cassell’s Dictionary of Slang* (Jonathon Green, 2005) says the “fly into the sea” sense of *ditch* is first attested in print in 1941,[²](http://books.google.com/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&lpg=PA412&ots=2ykVO9cdz1&dq=ditch%20slang%20term%20%22english%20channel%22&pg=PA412#v=onepage&q=ditch%20slang%20term%20%22english%20channel%22&f=false) and *Oxford English Dictionary* agrees. This connection between *Ditch* and *ditch* is also the opinion of online etymologists and military historians, as you can see if you google [`[ ditch slang term "english channel" ]`](https://www.google.com/search?q=ditch%20slang%20term%20%22english%20channel%22).

The term quickly graduated from slang to military jargon, and to this day is still the proper term used in aeronautical training and flight manuals.

Answer (score 7):

When several major dictionaries ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ditch), [British English](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ditch_3)) and pilot training guides ([here](http://scott757200.hubpages.com/hub/How-To-Ditch-An-Airplane) and [here](http://flighttraining.aopa.org/magazine/1998/November/199811_Flying_Smart_Lets_keep_our_fingers_crossed.html)) and news-stories ([here](http://www.pilotfriend.com/safe/safety/ditching.htm) and [here](http://www.cnn.com/2011/10/08/us/hawaii-plane-emergency)) all agree on an aviation term, namely that to ditch a plane is to make "a forced landing in water", clearly they are correct and various members of this community are mistaken.

The etymological distinction between "to ditch" and "to crash-land" an airplane seems to result from the distinction between the actions taken by the pilot after a forced landing (the generic term); the pilot must perforce abandon the plane after ditching in order to avoid drowning, but need not abandon the plane after a crash-landing unless fire is a hazard.

While all usage examples that I could locate referred to fixed-wing aircraft, all descriptions seemed to refer to aircraft generally, not specifically fixed-wing. My inference from this is that the terminology is identical for fixed- and rotary-wing aircraft, and in both cases a forced landing in water is a *ditching* of the aircraft.

**Update** - from the Australian national aviation authority:
[Prepare to Ditch (PDF)](http://www.casa.gov.au/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS%3aOLDASSET%3a%3asvPath=/fsa/2005/feb/,svFileName=24-34.pdf) which specifically, and exclusively, discusses forced landings on water.

The term is an aeronautical one, [invented by aviators in 1941](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ditch); it is incumbent on us to accept their definition when discussing their industry and field of expertise.

Comment: [NBC on ditching in a field](http://www.nbcdfw.com/news/local/Drug-Plane-Ditched-in-Caddo-Mills-Officials-Say-98761499.html). Just because dictionaries do not show the usage does not mean it is not done; it's obviously an extension of the documented usage coined because ***there isn't another word***.